# TFS 2012 Removing Entire TFVC Repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I am interested in removing a TFVC repository from a TFS server and solely using git repositories.

There is no code in the TFVC repo and would just like it gone.
[image]

In the image I am looking to remove $/CLLORSAEXTR and keep the Git Repositories.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are using TFS2012? Seems impossible, this feature seems not available  until TFS2015 update1 ... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3612921-support-tfvc-and-git-repositories-in-the-same-team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can not be deleted completely unless you delete the team project entirely.

Project Managers who create projects have to select the default version control type for the project, but if they select wrongly, there's nothing the developers can do about it.  I think it's more like a symbol which stands for the project is using TFVC as source control.

So it's **not able to remove the originally generated TFVC repo**, if you really don't like this. You could create a new team project and select the default type to Git.

You could also add a [uservioce](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services?query=Be%20able%20to%20get%20installed%20TFS%20version%20(including%20TFS2015%2FTFS2017)%20by%20using%20TFS%20API%20or%20Rest%20API), TFS PM will kindly review the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a TFVC repository once it's created. If you don't want people to use it, just remove their permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the git repo(s) locally, delete the team project entirely (TFSDeleteProject), recreate the team project as one with only Git... then force push your local repo(s) back into the new team project. You would lose any work items if you used this approach.

And be careful - make sure you've got backups :)